# R: Sparse matrix conversion without observing outcome

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix, categorical-data

Say you have the following toy data, where each unique observation (`id`), can have multiple features and multiple traits. How would I convert the following data frame such that the feature and trait columns would be converted into a sparse matrix of dummy variables? The end product should be such that the number of rows is equal to the number of unique `id`s, and there should be one column for each level of the feature and trait variables, encoded with 0's or 1's. I believe this approach is called one-hot-encoding.

```
set.seed(123)
fakedf <- data.frame(id = sample(seq(1,5,1),10,replace=TRUE),
           feature = sample(seq(1,50,1),10,replace=TRUE),
           trait = sample(seq(50,100,1),10,replace=TRUE))
```

I've seen examples where the sparse matrix is fed a formula. However, I want to eventually merge `fakedf` with `fulldf`

```
fulldf <- data.frame(id = seq(1,5,1),
                     trait2 = sample(seq(1,3,1),5,replace=TRUE))


merge(fulldf,fakedf,by=id)
```

so I can get a data set to do with predictive modeling with.

Comment: @MrFlick thanks, missed set.seed() during copy/paste. updated my post with more info.

Comment: So you want a 5 x 150 matrix? That's not what I understand to be a "sparse matrix" at least not in the sense of recording just the col and row values for entries.